# Android Text Service Dictionary

Tags: android

Which dictionary does the android text service use while getting spelling corrections([Spell Checker Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html))?
Can we access it or add to it?

In the documentation it says that it uses the metatdata in a class called [SuggestionsInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SuggestionsInfo.html).